# how to show a confirm pop up on selecting a option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown having options select, reject and approve . i want taht when reject option is selected from dropdown a confirm popup  will show ." Are you sure you want to reject this?
OK Cancle".

```
   <script type ="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".decision").click( 'change',function() {
            var decision = $(this).val();
    if(decision == Reject);
    {
    var question = 'Are you sure you want to ' + $(this).'Bill ?';
    if ( confirm( question ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
    }
    }  
    });
 });



   echo "<p>";
   echo form_label('Approve/Reject', 'decision');
   echo "<br />";
   echo form_dropdown('decision' ,$decision, $decision_active,"class =\"decision\"");
   echo "</p>";
```

Comment: is Reject a java script variable ? i don't think so, change `if(decision == Reject);` to `if(decision == "Reject")` and use on change instead of click.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` function to bind `change` event

change

```
$(".decision").click ...
```

to

```
$(".decision").on('change', function() {
     //code here
})
```